# Code combination in microsoft access (yyxxxx format)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I'm struggeling with a part of code that I want to implement in Microsoft Access.

The required code is used for project asignments.
The code format contains the last 2 numbers of the year + 4 digits which add up until a new year, then the last 2 numbers of the year add up with 1 and the 4 digits start at 1 again.
For example:

2019:
190001 = first task;
190002 = second task;
 etc...

2020:
200001 = first task;
200002 = second task;
 etc...

Could anybody help me out how to code this in Microsoft Access, preferably by VBA?
This way I can asign the code to a "submit" button to avoid similar numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your code saved to a database somewhere?  How would you like to address a returning entry, lets say your last saved was 200025, do you want the next one to increment up from the last saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formatting your code given an integer could be achieved in several ways, here is one possible method:

```vb
Function ProjectCode(ByVal n As Long) As Long
    ProjectCode = CLng(Format(Date, "yy") & Format(n, "0000"))
End Function
```

```vb
?ProjectCode(1)
 200001 
?ProjectCode(2)
 200002 
?ProjectCode(100)
 200100
```

Comment: Next question of OP:how do I get the ProjectCode argument;) If you want to I provide  the function for that to use as arg for your function: Check for n beeing smaller than 10000 should be added to your ProjectCode (and returns 0 to indicate False if not).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to assign the *next* task id to a project.

So, look up the latest id in use and add 1 to obtain the next task id:

```
NextTaskId = (Year(Date()) \ 100) * 10000 + Nz(DMax("TaskId", "ProjectTable", "TaskId \ 10000 = Year(Date()) \ 100"), 0) Mod 10000 + 1
```

*Nz* ensures that a task id also can be assigned the very first task of a year.